# How to use Fermat's Little theorem in $12^{12^{12}}\mod{17}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

The answers says

"According to Fermat's little theorem, $12^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$."

My question: Why is $12^{16}$ interesting? How do we get $12^{16}$ from $12^{12^{12}}$?

The answers then say

"Therefore we calculate $12^{12} = 144^{6} \equiv 0^6 \pmod{16} = 0$.

My question: Why $12^{12}$? Why $\mod{16}$?

Comment: Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?  Do you know how to find the residue of $12^{12}$ modulo $16$? Readers will be more responsive if you fill in some details you do understand.

Comment: See [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033639/mod-of-numbers-with-large-exponents-modular-order-reduction) in the linked dupe, which explains how to reduce modular powers mod *any* known period (cycle), e.g. the least length period (= order). See the linked posts there for many worked examples. Above, by lil Fermat, $16$ is a known period of $12^x\pmod{\!17}\,$ (i.e. $\,12^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{17}\,$ so $12^n\equiv 12^{n\bmod 16},\,$  Yours is case $n = 12^{12}\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence

> Therefore we calculate $12^{12}=144^6\equiv0^6(mod\ 16)=0$

is simply proving that $12^{12}$ is divisible by $16$.

After it's proven, we can state $12^{12}$ in the form $16k$ where $k$ is a positive integer. So,

$$12^{12^{12}}=12^{16k}=(12^{16})^k\equiv1^k=1(mod\ 17)$$

Comment: Thanks. My provided answer citation didn't make it clear if they are talking about the (12^12) in the "bottom" or on "top" and your answer made it clear.